# Getting this RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1 while trying to populate json data to ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an API and what I am trying to do is to display the `'CourseTitle'` from the JSON into the `ExpansionTile` title and the corresponding 'Title', 'EndDate', 'QuizStatus' in the children of ExpansionTile.

If data is not available for corresponding 'Title', 'EndDate', 'QuizStatus' etc.,  only 'CourseTitle' should be added to the ExpansionTile title, and children should be empty.

The first tile is built as expected but the remaining screen shows a red screen with `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1`.

I'm aware that this is because of empty data from JSON but couldn't solve the issue.

Here's JSON response:

```
{
    "QuizzesData": [
        {
            "request_status": "Successful",
            "CourseCode": "ABC101",
            "CourseTitle": "ABC Course",
            "UnReadStatus": [],
            "Quizzes": [
                {
                    "QuizID": "542",
                    "Title": "Test Quiz 01",
                    "StartDate": "Oct 20, 2022 12:00 AM",
                    "EndDate": "Oct 31, 2022 11:59 PM",
                    "IsDeclared": "False",
                    "Questions": "5",
                    "TotalMarks": "5",
                    "MarksObtained": "1",
                    "MarksObtainedTOCheckQuizResult": "1",
                    "QuizIsDeclared": "Un-Declared",
                    "StudentSubmitStatus": "true",
                    "IsRead": "1",
                    "QuizStatus": "Attempted"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "CourseCode": "DEF101",
            "CourseTitle": "DEF Course",
            "UnReadStatus": [],
            "Quizzes": []
        },
        {
            "CourseCode": "GHI101",
            "CourseTitle": "GHI Course",
            "UnReadStatus": [],
            "Quizzes": []
        },
        {
            "CourseCode": "JKL101",
            "CourseTitle": "JKL Course",
            "UnReadStatus": [],
            "Quizzes": []
        },
 
    ]
}
```

Here's the API data:

```
  var listofdata ;
  Future quizListingApi() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('json url'));
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
       listofdata = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
     }
     else{
    print(response.statusCode);
     }
```

and the build method:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: FutureBuilder(
            future: quizListingApi(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                return Text('Loading');
              }
              else{
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: listofdata['QuizzesData'].length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ExpansionTile(
                              title: Text(listofdata['QuizzesData'][index]['CourseTitle']),
                            children: [
                              Text(listofdata['QuizzesData'][index]['Quizzes'][index]['Title']),
                              Text(listofdata['QuizzesData'][index]['Quizzes'][index]['EndDate']),
                              Text(listofdata['QuizzesData'][index]['Quizzes'][index]['QuizStatus']),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                    }
                );
              }
            },
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I also tried answers from other similar threads but couldn't find the solution for this specific type of problem.

Comment: your Quizzes may have one item or two or be empty right? how do you want show the Quizzes when it has more than one item?

Comment: QuizzesData may have multiple Quizzes. If Quizzes are not empty, Quizzes title and other information is shown into the children of ExpansionTile. if empty/null, ExpansionTile still should be built but with no children.

Comment: can you add the ui design you want to achieve? because you need to change your widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Quizzes's` index are not same as your `listofdata`, so you need and other for loop for your `Quizzes's` items:

```
ExpansionTile(
  title: Text(listofdata['QuizzesData'][index]['CourseTitle']),
  children: List<Widget>.generate(listofdata['QuizzesData'][index]['Quizzes'].length, (i) => Column(
    children: [
        Text(listofdata['QuizzesData'][index]['Quizzes'][i]
        ['Title']),
    Text(listofdata['QuizzesData'][index]['Quizzes'][i]
        ['EndDate']),
    Text(listofdata['QuizzesData'][index]['Quizzes'][i]
        ['QuizStatus']),
    ],
  ),),
),
```

Comment: This solved the issue. However, I couldn't understand the logic.

Comment: You can't use same index that used for listofdata['QuizzesData'] also for Quizzes, because they are different list, you need and other index for Quizzes.